# How do I make my 'Import Data' function available in SQL when it is greyed out?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I intend on using the 'Import Data' function to import excel files in SQL server management studio 2018 however, the option seems to be greyed out? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that either you don't have permissions, or the server doesn't have SSIS installed.